# Wood stove as auxiliary to heat pump

Tags: heating

Existing appliances (https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvKvm.jpg)
I bought a home this year and it was built in 1978. There was no disclosure statement for the house so I have no knowledge of its history or anything else. It has a heat pump with an auxiliary wood stove connected via ductwork. The wood stove has two blowers (draft and circulator). I’m using it for the second time this year and have a couple questions for anyone who might be able to answer.
1. Will the heat pump and associated thermostat automatically come on when it detects heat from the wood stove? How should the thermostat be set (Off, Heat, Fan on, Fan auto)?
2. When the wood stove is heated and blowers running, heat is circulating to the house but there is also a slight odor of wood smoke. How can I be sure the fire box is sealed off from the surrounding area that collects and circulates heated air?
I would greatly appreciate any advice or help. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at the wood stove blowers, heat pump indoor unit, and thermostat?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Without more information (and maybe a LOT more information), any answer will be some variant of "Maybe...".